# Am I entitled to a refund on a non-refundable booking that has been cancelled by the hotel

Tags: bookings, hotels, cancellations, covid-19

I made a non-refundable hotel room booking through hotels.com. The hotel has contacted me to inform me that they will not be open for business during my stay because of the Coronavirus. I know I made the booking under the title "non-refundable", but my understanding is that I am not entitled to a refund only if I am the one to cancel the booking. I assume that, given the fact that the cancellation is not being made at my end and instead my order is not being fulfilled, I am entitled to a refund under EU contract law.

Edit: The hotel did not charge me for the booking. My card has been charged by hotels.com. If I cancel the booking through hotels.com's website it says I will not be refunded any money.

Comment: What did the hotel say about a refund? How did you pay - by credit card?

Comment: The hotel says that they will accept free cancellation because they didn't charge anything. The charge has been made to my card by hotels.com.

Comment: Have you contacted hotels.com? And/or your credit card provider? They will raise a chargeback claim if you do not receive the goods or service you’ve paid for from a supplier.

Comment: Are you sure it was an actual charge and not just an authorisation? Also, did the hotel post the cancellation on hotels.com?

Comment: "Non-refundable" means in case *you* cancel. In case *they* cancel, of course it's refunded -- otherwise all hotels would operate exclusively on the basis of getting paid for reservations and then cancelling them without consequences.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If hotel is cancelling, you will get refund. Since hotel said that they didn't charge, you have two things to do.

1. Contact booking site, hotels.com and explain the situation and ask them to reverse the charge.
2. If they are non responsive, contact the credit card provider and say that you are disputing the charge, as you didn't get the service. Mention that you didn't initiate the cancellation.

You will get your money back by then.

Comment: Start by asking the hotel to make sure they posted the cancellation (correctly identified as initiated by them) to the booking site.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention timescales; it's likely refunds are taking a while at this time, but sooner or later there should be a refund.

Comment: "You will get a refund" is a little too categorical. For example, the hotel may go bankrupt and while you're entitled to a refund you may never get it because the money is simply not there anymore.

Comment: @user2705196 Depending on the contract with the agency (hotels.com) one would get the refund from the agency anyway as the contrct was made with them and not with the hotel directly.

Comment: @user2705196 Even if agency refuses, you can dispute with credit card company and they are bound to give back the money, if you didn't receive the service you paid for.

Comment: [Even in case of insolvency] you would only stand to lose out in this if your booking was paid by **debit** card, which is not protected. This is one very very good reason to **always** pay by at least credit card, but better still, PayPal. When Monarch went down we had our money back from PayPal in 3 days. Credit cards took 6 weeks, debit… didn't happen; maybe they'll get something once the administrators have paid everybody else off.

Comment: @Tetsujin These differences vary from country to country. What you are referring to is the US situation.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have experienced in India and Singapore - Debit card transactions can be disputed and you will get refund if you didn't receive the service or product. It will take time, but will work.

Comment: @VladimirF - I'm referring to EU, specifically UK [when it was still fully in the EU] Anish - you can dispute all you like but if the company goes bust you're at the mercy of the administrators who took over, you have no 'insurance' coverage from the debit card company.. The details of this should really be a topic for https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tetsujin No such distinction for chargebacks exists here in the Czech republic (EU). UK is no longer in the European Union, BTW. You can requests chargebacks the same way for debit and credit cards. There is no extra protection for credit cards unless the card promises some insurance as an extra feature.

Comment: @VladimirF You are correct. Disputing a debit card charge during bankruptcy may not work. This is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

It might actually depend on where the hotel is.

Yes, EU contract law normally guarantees that you are entitled to a refund, but there are some EU governments that have taken extraordinary measures in order to reduce the monetary stress on the hotel and culture sector. For example, the Belgian government has taken some measures that allow the travel sector to forego the refunding of package tours and stays, on the condition that they provide a travel voucher for the same value that's valid for at least 1 year. You can find information in https://www.vrt.be/vrtnws/nl/2020/03/18/minister-muylle-maatregelen-reizen-en-evenementen/ (It is Dutch, yes, but Google translate works well enough for a readable translation).

I recommend you check the official site for the health department of the country you are visiting as well as their news sites to verify if there are any active measures in the relevant country that may impact your right to a refund.

Comment: I beg to differ. Regardless of location he will get the refund. Booking.com is a reputable organization and there is **no way** they won’t refund the money when they find out it’s not the travelers fault.

Comment: @user56513 I'm not saying he might not get the refund. I'm saying he might have to prepare for a delay in the refund, or for a refund through a voucher or other non-transferable value holder.

Comment: @user56513 I would challenge your assumption that they are a reputable organization and thus there is no way they won't refund the money (at least without strong pushback from your part). Besides, the OP said it was in hotels.com, not booking.com Those sites belong to different groups.

Comment: @Ángel Sorry for the wrong name. I use hotels.com extensively. They do not have top notch customer service however my position stands. This is such a clear cut case there is no way they won’t refund the money with minimal prodding.