# Getting refunded for a non-refundable booking due to the hotel closure because of the COVID-19 situation (Netherlands)

Tags: hotels, netherlands, cancellations, refunds, covid-19

I made a non-refundable hotel room booking through the hotel website. The hotel is located in the Netherlands.

Two days ago, a hotel manager informed me that they close the hotel for a certain period that included the period of my stay due to the Coronavirus, and that is why they were forced to move my reservation to another date. However, I do not want to move my reservation and would like to get the money back because I did not cancel my reservation, so I informed the hotel about it. The hotel, however, states that they are forced to move my reservation to another date as I made a non-refundable booking.

I checked [the official website of the government of the Netherlands](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19) as was advised [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155017/am-i-entitled-to-a-refund-on-a-non-refundable-booking-that-has-been-cancelled-by) and the rules of the hotel on their website but have not found anything on this matter. The rules, however, are on Dutch, so I could misunderstand or skip something (I do not speak Dutch at all).
As far as I understand the situation based on [John's question and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155017/am-i-entitled-to-a-refund-on-a-non-refundable-booking-that-has-been-cancelled-by), I am entitled to a refund. Are there some documents that I can cite to the hotel to get a refund?

P.S. My sister booked the same hotel for the same dates (non-refundable hotel room booking as well) but through Booking. She was able to get a refund after several e-mails. However, she made the booking from Russia ([the Netherlands deny the entry for foreigners having a tourist visa](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/qas-travel-restrictions-for-the-netherlands)), while I did it from Germany where I have permanent residency.

Answer (score 2):

Did you contact them?

They try to move the bookings, so that they have the money (liquidity) to pay employers. They could be in trouble if all clients will ask refund (there could ask government for help).

But you booking is a contract, so they are required to fulfill the contract on the data you both agreed, or they must refund you.  Just they try (maybe with a better offer) to keep booking (and money) for a later period.

The website booking.com doesn't get money from you (you will pay the hotel), so they have no really interest to have the "move booking" default.

So try to contact them, and think: do you want to book in a later date? In that case you may try to get a very good offer. But they must refund you.

The last step, it is to contact your credit card, and get the money back from them, because you were charged a service they will not offer you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I totally understand the situation but due to my personal reasons I do not want to move my reservation. Yes, I contacted the hotel and mentioned that I would like to get a refund (I have mentioned it in my question as well as their negative reply). That is why I am asking about the documents I can cite to not just reply them: "You must refund me".

Comment: @colombien The hotel is already aware of their contractual obligations. They're choosing to ignore them, to maintain their cashflow. "Citing documents" isn't going to prove anything new.

Comment: I do not think you should add some documents, they know they should refund you. In Europe contracts between business and private people requires "fair" clauses on private part (the "weak" part). If you want to add some empathy, just tell them that because of effects of CoVid19 on your job, you cannot do such travel this year. you do not need to give reasons, or point to law. -- and if you want to go more aggressively, just tell them that if you receive no refund, you must notify the credit card company. they do not want to have trouble with them (and CC get such request also on normal times)

Comment: Card providers will very likely have started to hold back money paid to hospitality businesses by card some time ago in order to try to minimise their losses. The hotel won’t have the cash flow to refund you. Go direct to your card provider, assuming that’s how you paid.

Comment: Agreed on filling a "Chargeback" if you used your credit card.